# Play can't find play.db.DBModule on the classpath

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, classpath, guice

I am trying to use Play 2.4 with MyBatis but still keep the HikariCP connection pooling and the new Guice based dependency injection.

When trying to view a page I get the following error:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.db.Database was bound.
```

However it should be bounded from inside `play.db.DBModule` located in `play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.2.jar`, right?

So I added it forcefully to the `application.conf` (which should not be necessary, because it is already in the `reference.conf` of the Jar by adding

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.db.DBModule"
```

Which makes the error worse:

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load module[Module [play.db.DBModule] cannot be instantiated.]
...snip...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.db.DBModule
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1.apply(Module.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
... 36 common frames omitted
```

Woot? óÒ
This clearly indicates that the thing is not on the classpath (or can't be found by the classloader), right? But it should be!

When I ask `activator` to `show fullClasspath` it shows me that `Attributed(/Users/<me>/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-jdbc_2.11/jars/play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.2.jar)` is included.
Might be lying. But even asking `lsof -p <PID>` tells me that the process has claimed the file.

This is my `build.sbt`, anyone has any ideas what I might do wrong?

```
name := """MyBatisWithGuiceAndPlay"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  jdbc,
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0",
  "org.mybatis" % "mybatis" % "3.3.0",
  "org.mybatis" % "mybatis-guice" % "3.6",
  "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-multibindings" % "4.0",
  "org.freemarker" % "freemarker" % "2.3.23",
  "org.webjars" % "yui-pure" % "0.5.0",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4",
  "org.webjars" % "select2" % "4.0.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "datatables" % "1.10.7",
  "org.webjars" % "datatables-fixedheader" % "2.1.2-1"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `jdbc` with `javaJdbc`. `build.sbt` java dependencies are prefixed with `java` and follow `play.*` package name convention. Scala dependencies reside in `play.api.*` packages.

Comment: Oh gosh, I knew that about the package names `play.*` and `play.api.*` but I was not aware that the dependencies have a prefix as well. \*blush\*